# Como solucionar este Warning?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, style

Tengo este Warning:

```
The component styled.header with the id of "sc-carFqZ" has been created dynamically.
You may see this warning because you've called styled inside another component.
To resolve this only create new StyledComponents outside of any render method and function component.
```

No entiendo exactamente cual es el problema. Pero creo que es porque quiere que le de estilos al componente `Showcase.js` dentro del componente `App.js` ?

App.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Nav from './components/Nav';
import Message from './components/Message';
import Showcase from './components/Showcase';
import Loader from './components/Loader';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [codCountrySelected, saveCodCountrySelected] = useState(null);
  const [optionSelected, saveOptionSelected] = useState(null);

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  let url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${codCountrySelected}&category=${optionSelected}&apiKey=4dc2f56899c94121919a5ba5b43406d8`;

  useEffect(() => {
    // Cleaning the screen
    setData([]);

    const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);

      try {
        const res = await fetch(url);

        if (!res.ok) {
          let err = new Error('Error en la petición');
          err.status = res.status || '00';
          err.statusText = res.statusText || 'Ocurrió un error';
          throw err;
        }

        const json = await res.json();
        setData(json.articles);
      } catch (error) {
        setData(null);
        setError(error);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [url]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Nav
        saveOptionSelected={saveOptionSelected}
        saveCodCountrySelected={saveCodCountrySelected}
      />
      {loading && <Loader />}
      {codCountrySelected === '' ? (
        <Message msg="You must enter a country" bgColor="#dc3545" />
      ) : null}
      {data.length > 0 ? (
        <Showcase optionSelected={optionSelected} data={data[0]} />
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Showcase.js

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Showcase = ({ optionSelected, data }) => {
  // Extracting Information
  const { urlToImage, url, title, description, source } = data;

  let category =
    optionSelected.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + optionSelected.slice(1);

  const Header = styled.header`
    color: #fff;
    background: #333;
    padding: 2rem;
    position: relative;

    .showcase-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 50vh;

      .showcase-content {
        z-index: 1;

        p {
          margin-bottom: 1rem;
        }
      }
    }

    &:before {
      content: '';
      background: url(${urlToImage}) no-repeat center center/cover;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      opacity: 0.4;
    }
  `;

  return (
    <Header>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="showcase-container">
          <div className="showcase-content">
            <div className="category category-sports">{category}</div>
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            <p>{description}</p>
            <a href={url} className="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">
              Read More
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Header>
  );
};

export default Showcase;
```

Answer (score 1):

El warning aparece porque estás usando tu variable `urlToImage`, lo que hace que el mismo styled.header sea dinámico. Para comprobar que el error proviene del uso de esa variable, asignale un valor por defecto y verás que desaparece.

Teniendo en cuenta que tu variable `urlToImage` contendría *n* posibilidades, como posibles soluciones te sugiero que:

- O uses solo una etiqueta div y le pongas una clase que represente a todos los estilos que tiene tu styled.header.
- O crees un componente header y como prop le pases la variable `urlToImage`(luego pasas las demás etiquetas como *childrens*).

Comment: Noté que a tu categoría conviertes la primera letra a mayúscula, te sugiero que esa lógica lo pases a un helper con el nombre que quieras(_capitalize_ por ejemplo) ya que esa logica suele ser usado en más de un lugar de una aplicación(incluso en otros proyectos) y no es algo muy propio de tu logica.

Comment: Pude resolver los warnings dando estilos en linea al div y pasando la variable urlToImage como background y para los demas estilos cree un archivo css porque no puedo pasar la variable urlToImage al el archivo css. Por lo tanto no quedo como estaba en un principio porque además aplico un pseudoelemento y ahí agrego la imagen urlToImage como fondo pero no se como hacerlo en react